# Aggregate a list using keys from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe containing lists of stings and floats, lets say

```
                        Names                    Prob
           [Anne, Mike, Anne]      [10.0, 10.0, 80.0]
   [Sophie, Andy, Vera, Kate]  [30.0, 4.5, 5.5, 60.0]
         [Josh, Anne, Sophie]            [51, 24, 25]
```

What I want to do is to loop over `Names` and if a name is contained in a predefined group, relabel it and then aggregate the corresponding numbers from `Prob`.

For example if `team1 = ['Anne', 'Mike', 'Sophie']` I want to end up with:

```
                          Names                    Prob
                     [Team_One]                 [100.0]
   [Andy, Kate, Team_One, Vera]  [4.5, 60.0, 30.0, 5.5]
               [Josh, Team_One]                [51, 49]
```

What I have written is this, but I think it is kinda ridiculous TBH, I am creating a temporary dataframe inside the loop and then do the grouping; sounds like an overkill to me and too heavy.

Is there a more efficient way please? (I am using Python 3 if that matters)

```
import pandas as pd


def pool(df):
    team1 = ['Anne', 'Mike', 'Sophie']

    names = df['Names']
    prob = df['Prob']
    out_names = []
    out_prob = []
    for key, name in enumerate(names):
        # relabel if in team1 otherwise keep it the same
        name = ['Team_One' if x in team1 else x for x in name]

        # make a temp dataframe and group by name
        temp = pd.DataFrame({'name': name, 'prob': prob[key]} )
        temp = temp.groupby('name').sum()

        # make the output
        out_names.append(temp.index.tolist())
        out_prob.append(temp['prob'].tolist())

    df['Names'] = out_names
    df['Prob'] = out_prob
    return df


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Names':[['Anne', 'Mike', 'Anne'],
             ['Sophie', 'Andy', 'Vera', 'Kate'],
             ['Josh', 'Anne', 'Sophie']
    ],
    'Prob': [[10., 10., 80.],
             [30., 4.5, 5.5, 60.],
             [51, 24, 25]
             ]
})


out = pool(df)
print(out)
```

Thanks!

Comment: looks made for zip, but I don't know about the pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `defaultdict` for sum all values in list, then convert it to list of tuples and pass to DataFrame constructor:

```
from collections import defaultdict

out = []
for a, b in zipped:
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        if x in team1:
            d['Team_One'] +=y
        else:
            d[x] = y
    out.append((list(d.keys()), list(d.values())))

df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['Names','Prob'])
print (df)
                          Names                    Prob
0                    [Team_One]                 [100.0]
1  [Team_One, Andy, Vera, Kate]  [30.0, 4.5, 5.5, 60.0]
2              [Josh, Team_One]                [51, 49]
```

Solution working if no `0` values in `Prob`:

```
out = []
for a, b in zipped:
    n, p = [],[]
    tot = 0
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        if x in team1:
            tot +=y
        else:
            n.append(x)
            p.append(y)
    if tot != 0:    
        p.append(tot)
        n.append('Team_One')

    out.append((n, p))

df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['Names','Prob'])
print (df)
                          Names                    Prob
0                    [Team_One]                 [100.0]
1  [Andy, Vera, Kate, Team_One]  [4.5, 5.5, 60.0, 30.0]
2              [Josh, Team_One]                [51, 49]
```

In pandas working with lists is slow in columns, so best is first flatten lists:

```
from itertools import chain

lens = [len(x) for x in df['Names']]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'row' : np.arange(len(df)).repeat(lens),
    'Names' : list(chain.from_iterable(df['Names'].tolist())), 
    'Prob' : list(chain.from_iterable(df['Prob'].tolist()))
})
```

Then replace values with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and last aggregate `sum`:

```
team1 = ['Anne', 'Mike', 'Sophie']
df.loc[df['Names'].isin(team1), 'Names'] = 'Team_One'

df = df.groupby(['row','Names'], as_index=False, sort=False)['Prob'].sum()
print (df)
   row     Names   Prob
0    0  Team_One  100.0
1    1  Team_One   30.0
2    1      Andy    4.5
3    1      Vera    5.5
4    1      Kate   60.0
5    2      Josh   51.0
6    2  Team_One   49.0
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael. Especially your very first code snippet makes a lot more sense. I guess the line  `a, b in zipped` means `a, b in zip(df['Names'], df['Prob'])`. It is also around 15(!!) times faster that mine

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is no way to get around creating new lists to replace the old lists, as removing items from the original lists will be too costly. I thought this might be a viable solution to go through the names and probs, and if the name is not in team1, append the name and prob to a new list. If the name IS in team1, then don't add that name but instead keep a sum of probs encountered for team1 names. If that sum is nonzero after looping through every name of a row, then at least one team1 member has been found (ASSUMING all probs are positive numbers, which idk if that's true). Then at the end, we append 'Team_One' as a name and the sum of probs to the probs list (if sum is nonzero) and replace the dataframe's lists with these newly created lists.

```
def pool(df):
    # Set of team1 names for faster look up than a list
    team1 = {'Anne', 'Mike', 'Sophie'}

    for i, names in enumerate(df['Names']):
        # iterating through every row and initializing new lists to replace the name/prob lists
        new_names = []
        new_probs = []
        team1_prob = 0
        for name, prob in zip(names, df['Probs'][i]):
            # iterating through every name/prob pair.
            if name not in team1:
                # add the pair to the new lists if not in team1
                new_names.append(name)
                new_probs.append(prob)
            else:
                # keep a sum of probs for all team1 members found, but don't append their name
                team1_prob += prob
        if team1_prob != 0:
            # assuming all probs are positive, thus if any team1 member was found, team1_prob must be nonzero
            new_names.append('Team_One')
            new_probs.append(team1_prob)
        # replace lists in the original df
        df['Names'][i] = new_names
        df['Prob'][i] = new_probs

    return df
```